# How to copy a string into a char array with strcpy

Tags: c++, c, string, arduino

I my trying to copy a value into a char.

my char array is

```
char sms_phone_number[15];
```

By the way, could tell me if I should write (what the benefic/difference?)

```
char * sms_phone_number[15]
```

Below displays a string: "+417611142356"

```
splitedString[1]
```

And I want to give that value to sms_from_number

```
// strcpy(sms_from_number,splitedString[1]);   // OP's statement 
strcpy(sms_phone_number,splitedString[1]);  // edit
```

I've got an error, I think because splitedString[1] is a String, isn't?

> sim908_cooking:835: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

So how can I copy it correctely.
I also tried with sprintf without success.

many thank for your help.
Cheers

Comment: Whats the type of `splitedString`? Looks like it is a `char*`

Comment: To the point of `char * sms_phone_number[15]`, that is an array of 15 different `char *`. So it can be used as a collection of strings, but only if you initialize the members to some value, else they'll only point you to undefined behavior.

Comment: Hello, splitedString is a char. splitedString[1] contain a phone number, like +41761111222. splitedString[2] contain another text, etc

Comment: That's all very confused. Perhaps you should post the whole code, not just snippets, so we can see the declarations.

Comment: @pierrot10 `splitedString` is not a `char`. It is most likely a `char**` or a `char*`. Your error makes it seem like a `char*`. In either case, `strcpy` only will work will null terminated strings which it doesn't look like you have.

Comment: so `splitedString` is `char *splitedString[]`? From the error, it appears you're using `char splitedString[]` and specifying a single value, `splitedString[1]`, which would be a `char`, or `sms_from_number` is only a `char`. Like other comments stated, the declarations of `sms_from_number` and `splitedString` will much improve the question.

Comment: -1, unclear what is your question

Comment: Hello, I added a answer with code

Answer (score 0):

I declare spliedString like this

```
// SlitString
#define NBVALS 9
char *splitedString[NBVALS];
```

I have that function
splitString("toto,+345,titi",slitedString)

```
void splitString(char *ligne, char **splitedString)
{

  char *p = ligne;

  int i = 0;
  splitedString[i++] = p;
  while (*p) {


    if (*p==',') {
      *p++ = '\0';
      if (i<NBVALS){
         splitedString[i++] = p;
      }
    } 
    else
    {
      p++;
    }

  }
  while(i<NBVALS){
    splitedString[i++] = p; 
  }
}
```

If I do a for with splitedString display, it display this

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
Serialprint(i);Serial.print(":");Serial.println(splitedString[i]);
}

//0:toto
//1:+4176112233
//2:14/09/19
```

I also declared and want to copy..

```
char sms_who[15];
char sms_phone_number[15];
char sms_data[15];
//and I want to copy 
strcpy(sms_who,splitedString[0]
strcpy(sms_phone_number,splitedString[1]
strcpy(sms_date,splitedString[2]
```

I know, I am very confused with char and pointer * :o(

Comment: If you are confused, **research** StackOverflow for some examples, using these keywords: "c++ array c-style string"

Answer (score 0):

The declaration:

```
  char * SplittedString[15];
```

Declares an **array of pointers** to characters, a.k.a. C-style strings.

Given:

```
  const char phone1[] = "(555) 853-1212";
  const char phone2[] = "(818) 161-0000";
  const char phone3[] = "+01242648883";
```

You can assign them to your `SplittedString` array:

```
  SplittedString[0] = phone1;
  SplittedString[1] = phone2;
  SplittedString[2] = phone3;
```

To help you a little more, the above assignments should be:

```
  SplittedString[0] = &phone1[0];
  SplittedString[1] = &phone2[0];
  SplittedString[2] = &phone3[0];
```

By *definition*, the `SplittedStrings` array contains pointers to single characters, so the last set of assignments is the correct version.

If you are allowed, prefer `std::string` to `char *`, and `std::vector` to arrays.

What you *need* is a vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> SplittedStrings(15);
```

**Edit 1:**

### REMINDER: Allocate space for your `spliedString`.

Your `spliedString` should either be a pre-allocated array:

```
  char spliedString[256];
```

or a dynamically allocated string:

```
  char *spliedString = new char [256];
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings and Chars can be confusing for noobs, especially if you've used other languages that can be more flexible.

```
char msg[40];  // creates an array 40 long that can contains characters
msg = 'a';     // this gives an error as 'a' is not 40 characters long 
(void) strcpy(msg, "a");              // but is fine : "a"
(void) strcat(msg, "b");              // and this    : "ab"
(void) sprintf(msg,"%s%c",msg, 'c');  // and this    : "abc"
```

HTH